# How to give duration in excel or libre calc?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, libreoffice-calc, openoffice-calc

I have duration data like 5:23, etc... in m:ss format. I already typed the data, but I cannot create a diagram, because none of the mentioned excels understand it. If I change the data type to user defined time with m:ss template, then it converts the data into something else. I tried to create new columns with this data type and copy-paste the data (including special paste etc...), but I got the same result. Is there a solution, or are these software really such a ...?

Comment: `Diagram` = chart? Can you be more specific about exactly what you want to do with the timestamp?  Excel charts understand dates/times and will chart them with little trouble.  The main issue comes down to whether or not the date/time is stored as a date/time or is stored instead as a string/text.  If it is stored as a date then everything works fine.

Comment: @ByronWall I want to do something like this: http://kepfeltoltes.hu/150710/javul_s_www.kepfeltoltes.hu_.png As you can see the m:ss is imported here as h:mm. That's all I could achieve. (these are running lap times per km) Ohh btw. there is a big difference between timestamp and duration.

Comment: You can change the number format for the axis to display `mm:ss` if the value is stored properly as a minute/second value.  The default for Excel is to interpret entry as `HH:mm` so you should enter as `00:mm:ss` if you want it to work by default.  You can also use `TIME()` to build the correct time with minutes and seconds entered.  Once you have the data entered correctly, the charting should just work.

Comment: @ByronWall I entered the data correctly. I won't override it, just because excel lacks data import feature. I would rather use plain json with a d3 chart than fixing manually what ms can't do for 10 years.

Comment: Not sure if the MS rant is getting us anywhere... you could do `=TIME(0,HOUR(A1),MINUTE(A1))` to "move" the HH:MM over to MM:SS.  The upside is that since it is a date formula, you are guaranteed to get a date/time for use in your chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I played around a bit LibreOffice Calc and you need time in the format `HH:MM:SS`.

But you can display it in the format `MM:SS`.

If you have time already as text `M:SS`  you can convert it to the correct time format at follows.

1. place text `M:SS` values in column A with type of text
2. put this formula in column B `=TIMEVALUE(CONCATENATE("0:"; A1))` it will change the `M:SS` input format into `HH:MM:SS`
3. Copy column B, and **special paste** it over A, no formula just values
4. Now format column to Time-> `MM:SS`

And there you have your data in the desired format, and Calc understands it.

Answer (score 1):

Calc and Excel need the first number in a time entry to be hours.  So if you are entering minutes you have to add a `0:` at the front of your duration: `0:5:23` etc. even though you have the cell formatted to not show the hour.

Alternatively you could have one column for minutes (say column A for this example), a second column for seconds (say column B), and use a calculation to diplay the entered time: `=A1/1440+B1/86400` where the division converts minutes and seconds respectively into fractions of 1 day (fractions of 1 day is how spreadsheets store time internally).  Copy and paste the formula down as far as needed.  (Of course the display column needs to be formatted as [mm]:ss or similar to display correctly.)

You could even get fancy and have the display column only show a value if you've entered numbers in the minutes or seconds column: `=IF(OR(A1<>"",B1<>""),A1/1440+B1/86400,"")`  Note that LibreOffice or OpenOffice would need semicolons `;` where Excel uses commas `,`

Comment: Sorry, I cannot accept solutions, which require data format changes. I want to give the durations as `m:ss`.

Comment: @Lyrl, Note that there is a `TIME` function which saves you from having to do math with minutes and seconds per day.